# Calling unmanaged code C++ dll from VB.NET

Tags: c++, vb.net, unmanaged

I have a problem to reuse a C++ DLL used from VB 6.0 to VB.NET.

A mate of mine programmed a code in VB6.0 that called to Ansi C++ DLL programmed in VC 6.0++.

The function is declared as following;

```cpp
CTYPE DWORD CCONV IniciaGestion(HWND newhventana, char *ficheroini, char *mensaerror)
```

The former code in VB6.0 called this dll in this way

```vb
status = IniciaGestion(Me.hWnd, "DRVCOMM2.ini", mensaerror)
```

where `mensaerror` is an output parameter defined as

```vb
Public mensaerror As String * 256
```

Now I can use this dll from VB.NET?

I have problem with the declaration of this third parameter.
I am using this declaration

```vb
<DllImport("GestionPrg.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
Public Shared Function IniciaGestion(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal a As Integer, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal b As String, <OutAttribute(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByRef c As String) As Long
```

and the function is called as following

```vb
Dim mensaerror As String

Class1.IniciaGestion(Me.Handle, "C:\\Windows\\DRVCOMM2.ini", mensaerror)
```

I am debugging and the function is called but when I am going to assigned value to `mensaerror` in the C++ code an exception is produced.

Can anyone help me in the declaration in VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Please use 4 whitespaces in front of your code - makes it a lot easier to read...

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("YourDLL.dll")> _
Public Shared Function IniciaGestion(ByVal a As IntPtr, ByRef b As String, ByRef c As String) As Long
End Function

Private Sub CallCode()
    Dim mensaerror As String = ""
    IniciaGestion(Me.Handle, "C:\Windows\DRVCOMM2.ini", mensaerror)
End Sub
```

Should do the job...

Comment: Unless you really know what you're doing, you never declare strings `ByRef` when calling to an external library in VB.

Answer (score -1):

```vb
Public Declare Ansi Function IniciaGestion Lib "GestionPrg.dll" (ByVal a As IntPtr, ByVal b As String, ByVal c As String) As Integer
```

And don't forget to allocate space for `c` before calling, e.g. by doing

```vb
Dim mensaerror As String = Space(256)
```

The more .NET way of doing this is to use a `StringBuilder` though:

```vb
Public Declare Ansi Function IniciaGestion Lib "GestionPrg.dll" (ByVal a As IntPtr, ByVal b As String, ByVal c As StringBuilder) As Integer
```

for which you set the required capacity before calling:

```vb
Dim mensaerror = New StringBuilder(256)
```

Comment: The 'more .NET way' is to *not* use 'Declare' - use the 'DllImport' attribute. 'Declare' is only in VB for backward compatibility with VB6.

Comment: You kind of missed the main point, but yes, that would arguably be even more .NET. Having that said, `Declare` is certainly not only for backward compatibility, for the reason that they added the `Ansi/Unicode/Auto` feature that was not present in the original VB, and they [do not mention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zey12w5.aspx) it is not recommended or deprecated, like they do for [actual backward-compatibility-only things](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compatibility.vb6(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The link you gave ('actual backward-compatibility ...') is just about the VB6 namespace. 'Declare' is VB6 syntax, not a VB6 namespace issue.